# What does "initializer = new configuration" do?

Tags: ruby

What does `initializer = new configuration` do?

```
def self.run(configuration = Configuration.new)
  yield configuration if block_given?
  initializer = new configuration
  initializer.
  initializer
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of that code is probably something like:

```
class MyClass
  def self.run
  ....
```

So self is MyClass.  Writing `new` is a shortcut for `self.new` which means `MyClass.new` which simply makes a new instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally I realized the usage.

Answer (score 2):

Let's step through these lines.

```
# It is a definition of a class method which takes one argument
# with a default value.    
def self.run(configuration = Configuration.new)
  # It passes the argument to a block if one was given.
  yield configuration if block_given?
  # It calls method `new` passing the `configuration` as
  # an argument. The returned value is saved in the local
  # variable.
  initializer = new configuration
  # Two following lines are a single expression: a call
  # to method `initializer` of the object pointed to by the
  # variable `initializer`, i.e.
  # 
  #   initializer.send :initializer
  # 
  # No idea why one would break this expression into two lines.
  # The value returned from the call to `initializer` becomes
  # the return value of the analysed method.
  initializer.
  initializer
end
```

Comment: `+1` from me for explanations!

Comment: Thanks for such detailed reply. :)